# What is a good way to make a foggy looking area without resources packs

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to make a silent hill map and need a section to be foggy but not the entire map. Any ideas?

Comment: Very short view distance? Then Blindness. Otherwise maybe particles, but that's probably extremely laggy. In 1.19.4, something might be possible with lots of huge transparent display entities. (Edit: Actualyl, this is MCBE. I don't know if that has display entities.)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Joachim i have no idea where to start and haven't really tried anything yet. Figured commands would be a good start idea but cant really think of what command or commands.

Answer (score 3):

Minecraft bedrock has built-in fogs (like the fog in the soulsand valley) that can be accessed manually via [the `/fog` command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/fog), which you can use to add one or more fogs to a player.

**Through resourcepacks** you can modify the existing fogs and even define your own. To make it work automatically, you can assign fogs to a biome (at the time of writing, unfortunately not all biomes can have fog), then changing the biome of the foggy part of the map will cause it to automatically apply the fog (like in the nether biomes). See https://bedrock.dev/docs/stable/Fogs for more information.

**Without a resourcepack** however you're stuck with the already existing fogs the game has. Try them, try to stack them, and maybe you'll find a combination that works for you. You can find a list of the built-in fogs in the first link above.